# Return rows between two dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to rows that have only been entered in the last 1 day.

I have a date column which stores `YYYY-MM-DD`, and I allow the user to send a date that they want to look at in this format `yyymmdd` how can I use this data to limit it to the previous day only?

I would imagine it is something to do with the `BETWEEN` keyword but I cant figure it out.

Comment: previous day = yesterday or (`yyyymmdd` - one day)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   mydate >= STR_TO_DATE('110321', '%y%m%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        AND mydate < STR_TO_DATE('110321', '%y%m%d')
```

will return all records for `Mar 20, 2011`

Comment: this works for me if I used the string '110321' however it doesn't if I use "STR_TO_DATE('$testDate', '%y%m%d')" it doesn't $testDate = $_POST['date']; $testDate = (string)$testDate); The format of $testDate = YYYYMMDD

Comment: @Herly: use `%Y%m%d` (note the uppercase `Y`) for four-digit years.

Comment: Nevermind it WAS because i was using YYYMMDD instead of YYMMDD. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT * from TABLE_NAME WHERE ROW_DATE BETWEEN '2011-03-20' AND '2011-03-21'
```

Comment: This will return records for `2011-03-21 00:00:00` as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL manual ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)):

```
SELECT something FROM tbl_name WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= date_col;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE date_column = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

This returns all rows for today and yesterday.